# Как переместить и переименовать файлы с одинаковым названием c#

Tags: c#

Как мне переместить файлы если у них названия одинаковы, то есть в результате перемещения будет так:
File
File(2)
File(3)
итд...
и второй вопрос:
есть папка с названием скажем test
в папке test есть папки 1,2,3,4 итд. И в каждой из этих папок(1,2,3,4) есть обычные приложения console application1 console application2 console application4 console application4 и соответственно файлы в каждом проекте совпадают с названием проекта.Вопрос: как через c# переименовать все возможные файлы с названием папке в которой они находятся то есть cons.app1 ,будет в результате 1 consapp2 -->2 ...... ?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь этим кодом:

```
int count = 1;

string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
string newFullPath = fullPath;

while(File.Exists(newFullPath)) 
{
    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
    newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
}
```

Он автоматически проверит существование файла с таким именем, и в случае наличия файла с таким именем, автоматически переименует в виде %имя файла%(%индекс%)

Comment: ничего не произошло

Comment: Вы вопрос поняли?